# Processing 3.2.1 Game Control Plus library java exception

Tags: java, controller, crash, processing, jbox2d

I'm studying Games & Apps Development and on our first semester we are building a game on Processing.
On my game I'm using a PS4 controller with the help of the library [Game Control Plus](http://lagers.org.uk/gamecontrol/index.html).
If I press a button enough times, my game crashes and gives this output on the console (the plug 'Uarma' is a function that executes the code when the button is pressed)

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.Plug.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.callPlugs(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlDevice.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlIO.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.createBody(World.java:339)
    at shiffman.box2d.Box2DProcessing.createBody(Box2DProcessing.java:203)
    at Meon$Bullet.<init>(Meon.java:202)
    at Meon.Uarma(Meon.java:294)
    ... 9 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error on calling plug: Uarma
    at org.gamecontrolplus.Plug.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.callPlugs(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlButton.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlDevice.update(Unknown Source)
    at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlIO.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My understanding of Java is not big so any help on what might be causing this error is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code involved in the process:

```java
//Variaveis
ControlIO controlo;
ControlDevice comando;

//inicia o ControlIO (vai ver que comandos estao ligados)
controlo = ControlIO.getInstance(this);

//procura comandos compativeis
comando = controlo.getMatchedDevice("playerControl");

//associa funçoes a botoes (Botão para Função)
BpFp1(); //p1 = player 1

void BpFp1() {

  comando.getButton("jump").plug(this, "salto", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
  comando.getButton("punch").plug(this, "murro", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
  comando.getButton("grabWep").plug(this, "Aarma", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
  comando.getButton("useWep").plug(this, "Uarma", ControlIO.ON_PRESS);
}

void Uarma() {

  println("usar armas? check");  
  bullets.add(new Bullet(player1.playerPos.x + 20, player1.playerPos.y, 5, 5));
}
```

Bullet constructor:

```
class Bullet {

  Vec2 bulletPos;
  Body bulletbody;
  float dbulletLarg;
  float dbulletAlt;

  Bullet(float bulletX, float bulletY, float bulletLarg, float bulletAlt) {

    //definir o corpo
    BodyDef bulletbd = new BodyDef();
    bulletbd.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
    bulletbd.bullet = true;
    bulletbd.position.set(box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(bulletX, bulletY));

    //criar o corpo
    bulletbody = box2d.createBody(bulletbd);

    //forma
    PolygonShape bulletps = new PolygonShape();
    bulletps.setAsBox(box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(bulletLarg/2), box2d.scalarPixelsToWorld(bulletAlt/2));


    //o que cola a forma ao corpo
    FixtureDef bulletfd = new FixtureDef();
    bulletfd.shape = bulletps;

    //parametros que afetam a fisica do objeto
    bulletfd.density = 0;

    //colar a forma ao corpo
    bulletbody.createFixture(bulletfd);

    dbulletLarg = bulletLarg;
    dbulletAlt = bulletAlt;

    bulletbody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vec2(100, 0), bulletbody.getWorldCenter(), true);
  }

  void display() {

    bulletPos = box2d.getBodyPixelCoord(bulletbody);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(bulletPos.x, bulletPos.y);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(0, 0, dbulletLarg, dbulletAlt);
    popMatrix();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why did you deleted this question from the portuguese site?

Answer (score 1):

This is a threading problem. `ControlIO` has its own thread for receiving input, as can be evidenced by this:

```
at org.gamecontrolplus.ControlIO.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, Box2D (under Processing hoods) manipulate its virtual world in its own thread too. You shouldn't manipulate virtual worlds outside of the thread used by Box2D. Doing this would risk data corruption problems due to unorderly thread interference.

To protect against that type of problems, Box2D locks its worlds in order to avoid unexpected manipulation. However it uses `assert`s instead of `IllegalArgumentException`s or `ConcurrentModificationException`s that most of other Java frameworks uses for that sort of checking. Hence, you see the `AssertionError` being throw from [this line of code](https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/dynamics/World.java#L339).

Unfortunately, this is just what you are doing. When you create a `Bullet`, you do so from the `ControlIO` thread. The `Bullet` constructor tries to add the `Bullet` to the virtual world. Box2D is offended and hits the `assert`.

The solution is to not create the `Bullet` inside the `Uarma` method. Instead, post an object in a list somewhere (with the proper synchronization) which says that a `Bullet` should be created in the given position. Back in your `Meon` code that actually handles the virtual world in Box2D's thread, consume the list adding the correspondent `Bullet`s into the virtual world by calling its constructor.